# Reading cycle notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I need a little help understanding how we read cycle notation. I know it is a function so if we have something like

$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5  \\
                2 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 1        
\end{pmatrix} = (1 \quad 2 \quad 5)(3 \quad 4)=(3 \quad 4)(1 \quad 2 \quad 5)=(3 \quad 4)(5\quad 1 \quad 2) $

how is it read? Thanks!

Comment: I am aware it is a function so we read right to left but I'm not totally clear on it.

Comment: Do you mean how do you read it aloud?  Or are you asking what the function is?  The way that you interpret that array is $1 \mapsto 2$,  $2 \mapsto 5$, $3 \mapsto 4$ and so on.  The way you interpret $(1~2~5)(3~4)$ is $1 \mapsto 2 \mapsto 5 \mapsto 1$ and $3 \mapsto 4 \mapsto 3$.

Comment: @Brian I removed my comment and tried to craft an answer to dispel any confusion I may have unintentionally caused by my original comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think my original comment may have led to some confusion in regards to my intentions behind it--your function
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5  \\\tag{1}
2 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 1        
\end{pmatrix}
may, perhaps, be more effectively communicated as
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5  \\
\downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow\\\tag{2}
2 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 1        
\end{pmatrix}
where each "$\downarrow$" in $(2)$ is really meant to be an upside down "$\mapsto$" (I'm not sure of the best way to rotate math symbols using MathJax). The point is that each number is being *mapped* to another. All of these mappings make up your function. Read aloud what happens in $(2)$:

- $1$ maps to $2$ which maps to $5$ which maps to $1$ which maps to $2$ which maps to $5$ ...
- $3$ maps to $4$ which maps to $3$ which maps to $4$ which maps to $3$ ...

The point is that *both* of the cases above lead to noticeable *cycles* (hence the name). By understanding how the different mappings in $(2)$ work, we can now understand how the cycles were created, yielding
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5  \\
2 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 1        
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 5\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 4\end{pmatrix}
$$

Does that help?